# Get unique identifier of a Cloud Function instance

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to access a unique identifier of the Goodle Cloud Function's current instance inside the function? When I check the function logs I can see there is an identifier to each instance. I would like to access this identifier inside the function while it is running. My intention to create unique folders with some content in one of my storage bucket after each invoked function. Besides being unique folders it would be also great that I can map those easyly with the function  which created it.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for. The unique identifier of what exactly? What sort of value are you expecting? What do you need to use it for?

Comment: the cloud function instance's unique identifier. When I check a given function's log i can see an identifier like: `1036455092956224`

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more specific about what you're seeing?  Please also explain what you intend to do with this data - why do you need it?

Comment: Sure, I updated it!

Comment: @Mark Pintye have these log identifiers been deprecated? When I view the functions log from the console now I see only timestamp and the console output. I too am searching for a way to identify functions instances, and EventContext is undefined for admin https calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're observing is not an "instance ID" and more like the event ID assigned by the event provider.  The second argument passed to every background function invocation is a context object that contains the event ID.  The purpose of this ID is to help you write functions that are idempotent.  They are not really intended to be universally unique.

I suggest that you just generate your own UUID using whatever standard library is available for the language you're using.  The chance of two UUIDs colliding is **astronomically small**, and you are guaranteed a "form" for that value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Also you made great videos on firebase :)

Comment: when it comes to generating our own UUID, does that means currently there is no field that can help us identify the uniqueness of GCF(cloud function)? I am assuming we have  resourceId(19 digits numeric value)to uniquely identify GCE(compute engine)