# How to get a resource identifier for a functions instance from admin?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to determine just how long the temp data persists in a Functions instance, in order to get the most out of my caching methods. I'm building a Unity game that keeps a small amount of state data cached in `os.tmpdir()` in order to reduce bandwidth from the realtime database. I want to get some kind of resource identifier like EventContext.resource in order to debug my caching. Admin does not provide a context object - it's undefined by default. Is there another way to determine the identity of the functions instance running my code? There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588028/get-unique-identifier-of-a-cloud-function-instance) from last year but it alludes to a feature of the functions log that seems to no longer be available.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand Cloud Function should be stateless. So it's not keeping any state.

In [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) we can find information:

> This is a local disk mount point known as a "tmpfs" volume in which
> data written to the volume is stored in memory.

As it is "stored in memory" I understand that it disappear when the execution function will end.

On the other hand there is [Tips and Tricks](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#always_delete_temporary_files) article where we can see hint to deleted the temporary files as:

> sometimes persist between invocations

So it's possible that some data will persist between invocation, however you cannot depend on this. If I understand correctly the question you want to leave some state in `/tmp` directory to be used by many invocation, and for me it rather not possible.

Comment: I hear you and while you are correct, the answer I'm looking for is how to identify the resource in progress so that, if possible, the temp cache can be updated and used to save even one database call. My current solution has the temp cache getting out of sync, i.e. containing data from 2 calls ago, which leads me to believe there are multiple resources running my command. I need to identify them to know when to use the cache and when to update it.